# order group by with left join condition

Tags: mysql

i have two tables
bt_produits :
prd_id, reference, color

bt_prd_photos
id, prd_id, url_photo

i want all product of first table group by reference

my difficulty is, in second table i don't have for one reference always a photo and i want prioritize reference with photo

```
**bt_produits**
prd_id reference color
1      tb 2020   blue
2      tb 2020   red
3      tb 2020   black
4      rf 20     grey 
5      hm 60     yellow 

**bt_prd_photos**
id prd_id url
1  3      img1.jpg
2  5      img2.jpg
```

i want this result

```
prd_id ref      color   url
3      tb 2020  black   img1.jpg
5      hm 60    yellow  img2.jpg
4      rf 20    grey
```

i try without success

```
SELECT * 
FROM `bt_produits` 
LEFT JOIN (select prd_id,nom from bt_prd_photos order by nom desc) 
     btphoto ON `bt_produits`.`prd_id` = `btphoto`.`prd_id`   
GROUP BY `bt_produits`.`reference`
```

```
SELECT * 
FROM `bt_produits` 
LEFT JOIN bt_produits ON `bt_produits`.`prd_id` = `bt_produits`.`prd_id`   
GROUP BY `bt_produits`.`reference` 
ORDER BY `url` desc
```

thanks for your help

Comment: How I understand you need to show 1 row for each reference, right? So what color need be shown in result record? Or you shows only records matched to second table?

Comment: hello sorry for delay i haven't see your question. I group by ref but i want to prioritize the group by with the second tab, if a have a img in a color, use it in group by